# FirstOrDefault working same as LastOrDefault for grid records

Tags: grid, blazor

I have a Telerik grid that needs buttons to select the First, Last, Previous, and Next records. I have the following methods so far, but all select the last row:

```
private void GoToFirstRow(){
    var firstRecord = GridDataSource.FirstOrDefault();
    var collectionOfFirstRecord = GridDataSource.Where(x => x.ID == firstRecord.ID);
    SelectedItems = new List<ReportRO>(collectionOfFirstRecord);
}
private void GoToLastRow(){
    var lastRecord = GridDataSource.LastOrDefault();
    var collectionOfLastRecord = GridDataSource.Where(x => x.ID == lastRecord.ID);
    SelectedItems = new List<ReportRO>(collectionOfLastRecord);
}
private void GoToPreviousRow(){
    int prevIndex = index - 1;
    var prevRecord = GridDataSource.ElementAt(prevIndex);
    var collectionOfPrevRecord = GridDataSource.Where(x => x.ID == prevRecord.ID);
    SelectedItems = new List<ReportRO>(collectionOfPrevRecord);
}
```

I thought maybe the "OrDefault" part in GoToFirstRow was the issue, so I switched "FirstOrDefault" to "First," but it didn't help.

Just to be thorough, here are my grid and related elements in brief:

```
   <TelerikGrid   Data="@GridDataSource"
             EditMode="@Telerik.Blazor.GridEditMode.Incell"
             @ref="Grid"
             SelectionMode="Telerik.Blazor.GridSelectionMode.Single"
             @bind-SelectedItems="@SelectedItems">
@code {
[Parameter]
public ReportCollection GridDataSource { get; set; }
public TelerikGrid<ReportRO> Grid;
public IEnumerable<ReportRO> SelectedItems { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<ReportRO>();
```

Comment: OrDefault means it doesn't throw error when there's no results, it just returns null

Comment: try debugging and see what's inside `firstRecord`, `lastRecord`

Comment: @buga Each of those is {SolutionName.BizObj.ReportRO}. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: that's the type, you need to check if it is what you expect, the first/last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't add IDs to my dummy records. Since they were all identical ID-wise and I tied the methods to the record IDs, there was no "first" record. It works now.